# Session Hijacking in Django 1.7.7 and python3

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions

I have developed a small application for submitting some data to database server(Oracle 11g). When we are reviewing security of this small application, we observed as follows:

```
1. We have deployed django with https and all secure configurations like Secure Cookie and Secure Session, No Cache, etc.
2. Using BURP tool for this sample review
3. We have created two different user in this system say Normal User and Admin User
4. Opened 2 browsers(Mozilla and IE 11), On mozilla we login with Admin user and captured session id using burp tool.
5. On second browser we login with Normal user and replaced session id Normal User with Admin User.
6. whoila......On second browser, I got Admin user access by just changing the session id
```

I have used default session backend for this application.

I would like to know whether this is flaw in django and how to resolve this issue..

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're worried about security, you shouldn't be using a version of Django that is unsupported and has not received patches for years

Answer (score 0):

This is an inherent risk of using session-based identification. It's called session hijacking, and if you search for that term you will find lots of information.

Mitigations generally have one of two goals: making it harder to steal the token, or making the damage less severe if it is stolen. In the former camp are techniques like using HTTPS and [`SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-httponly). In the latter are things like limiting the length of a valid session ([`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age)). In the end, though, it's difficult or impossible to stop someone from impersonating another user if they get their token, since that's the very thing that establishes identity.